# What does a wing shake in crickets indicate?

Tags: zoology, ethology

What does it mean when a male cricket (*Acheta domesticus*) shakes its wings towards another male cricket? Is this an act of aggressiveness?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit what you mean with shaking its wings? You mean chirping?